# Can ScheduledExecutorService go out of memory for large timeout value?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

My business scenario is like, we assign a user some resources [20-30], from a big resource table, if he/she doesn't respond back in due time[some configurable timeout value], we assign those resources to someone else. If he/she submits in time, we mark those resources as 'completed'.

Now, I am planning to use ScheduledExecutorService for this. Every time I assign a resource-package to a user, I put that reference in ScheduledPool, which gets executed after timeout value, checks if submission came, otherwise 'frees' the resources.

My concern is, if timeout value is configured high [more than 20 mins], so for starting 20 mins, I will keep 'adding' references in pool. Wouldn't it cause out of memory error, or in other words, wouldn't it go beyond pool 'capacity'.

Is there any optimised way of handling this scenario. A scheduled task is not preferable because there could be multiple timeouts for each resources in future. So, a scheduled task for freeing up resources will not be very efficient.

Comment: How many schedules do you think you'll be tracking?

Comment: Business scenario is for each user. As of now, we have 200 request/sec

Comment: 200 requests/sec times 20 minutes is 240000 scheduled tasks waiting to run.

Comment: Yes, and usage might go high in future.